# Unix/Linux find and replace function calls in multiple files

Tags: regex, linux, unix

I have a bunch of C source code files with calls like `free(ptr)`. I want to replace all those with `myfree(ptr)`. I know that the regex `(free)\(.*\)` will match `free`, but how do I replace only the `free` and not the part in parentheses? I've tried variants of

```
find . -name '*.txt' |xargs perl -pi -e 's/(free)\(.*\)/(myfree)\(.*\)/g'
```

That one ends up replacing `free(ptr)` with `myfree(.*)`, not what I want. I feel like this is a common question but haven't found anything.

Comment: `s/\bfree(\(.*\))/myfree$1/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
find . -name '*.txt' |xargs perl -pi -e 's/(free)(\(.*\))/myfree$2/g'
```

We're replacing `\(.*\)` with `$2` to indicate that we want it to be replaced with 2nd capture group.

Note that we've also enclosed `\(.*\)` separately within brackets.

Comment: That ended up turning `free(test)` into `(myfree)(test)`. melpomene's comment on the OP worked, though. I guess `myfree` shouldn't be in parentheses.

Comment: @sudo yes... I missed the bracket in resulting part. This should work now.